# wxGLCanvas exits process

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxglcanvas

I have a problem with the OpenGL canvas of the wx library. When I use the method `SwapBuffers` of `wxGLCanvas` the whole process will be terminated with exit code `1`.
If I remove the method call the program runs on and on. Unfortunately there is no GL drawing as well.

I think it is an internal problem of the wx library. Maybe due to some compiling issues or something like that.

Just wanted to know whether this problem has already happened to anybody else and if, how it was solved.

Edit: Solved. Used the wrong constructor and passed a NULL-reference as wxGLContext...

Comment: please close your question as "no longer relevant"

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have set WX_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER in Canvas [creation?](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.6/wx_wxglcanvas.html). In order to verify that your have OpenGL lib etc setup correctly, build and run one of the OpenGL tests available under wxWindows. I have used wxGL layer in past and it works fine. Most of the time it is setup issue.